# Chrome Extension not working on page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want that if any of my webpage loads I want to simply display a simple alert on the page.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Ext Demo",
  "description": "chrome extension tuts",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["http://*/* "],
      "js": ["jquery.js","eventPage.js"]
  }
],
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
 "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/"
  ]
}
```

I have jquery stored locally in my chrome extension folder.

eventPage.js

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    alert("hiii");
    console.log("hii");
});
```

I am new to building Chrome Extension. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please do not ask friends to upvote. this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @ZigMandel : I am professional not a noob.

Comment: it is absolutely impossible that anyone would upvote a basic, duplicated question like these. therefore the two upvotes you had must be from coworkers or friends.

Comment: @ZigMandel : I am not here to gain upvotes. I am here to get & share my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the useless space in your `"matches": ["http://*/* "]`field, it doesn't match a valid url.

If possible, remove useless `permissions` if they are not used.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Ext Demo",
  "description": "chrome extension tuts",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","eventPage.js"]
  }
],
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
 "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly but on some websites only..i also tried to run it on my localhost site but it is not working

Comment: @HarshKanakhara, you matches field only matches http sites now, when you are saying not working, does the site start with `https`? and for localhost site, does it start with `file://`?

Comment: yes..thank you..what to do so that it supoorts both http & https ?

Comment: @HarshKanakhara, you could use "<all_urls>" to match all or ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"] to match both https and http, see my updated anwser or https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns for more details